# matplotlib pylplot: plotting series of cumulative data as differences

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a data series which looks as follows:

```
times[]
values[]
```

The data in the values series are cumulative, so the value at position n is is equal to (n-1) + the change since the previous time.

I would like to the plot the difference between values.
E.g.

```
t[n] vs (v[n]-v[n-1])
```

Clearly it's possible for me to pre-compute the data by iterating over the values before plotting. However, I'm not from a mathematical background and strongly suspect that this is a pretty common operation and there are standard functions for doing this which I'm failing to find.

I've reviewed the standard matplotlib and pyplot documentation, as well as a number of tutorials found via google, but I'm not seeing something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in `numpy` that does this, it's called [`diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.diff(range(10))
Out[2]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

So you can do something like

```
plt.plot(times, np.diff(values))
```

Also note that the result of `diff` is one item shorter than the original list/array. So you need to have `values` 1 longer than `times`, or discard the first/last value of `times` by using `times[1:]` or `times[:-1]` in the `plot` call.